# Azure PowerShell cmdlet into Strings

Tags: powershell, azure

Just a quick question. I am running lines of code like,

```
$publicIP = Get-Content (Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $servicename -Name $vmsname | Get-AzureEndpoint | Select { $._vip })
$OSDisk = Get-Content (Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $servicename -Name $vmsname | Get-AzureOSDisk)
```

And it does get me the IPAddress or the variables, but when trying to put the value into a csv cell, it fails. I think it is because it tries to add the extra labels, but I do not know how to get just the string and set the variable as just that. Does anyone know how to remedy this?

edit:

If the output with:

```
Get-AzureVM -servicename "vm1" -name "vm1" | Select DNSName | Out-String
```

is like this:

```
DNSName                                                                                                                     
-------                                                                                                                     
http://example.cloudapp.net/
```

How do I just put in "http://example.cloudapp.net/" as a CSV-entry? Right now it is trying to put all of the code block into the CSV which is giving me awful formatting erros.

Comment: How you put the value in csv? You copy and past or you export to csv?

Comment: I append each parameter with commas and then out-file and ConvertTo-CSV. Then after the query I take the file and do Export-CSV. I'm going to update the post with the error.

Comment: This does not look right:  `| Select { $._vip })`

Answer (score 0):

`Select` is an alias for `Select-Object` and allows you to take one or more properties from an object and creates a new object with them.

If you want to expand a property into just the value, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
Get-AzureVM -servicename "vm1" -name "vm1" | Select -ExpandProperty DNSName
```

Should give you just `http://example.cloudapp.net/`

Also, when you want to send data to a CSV, you can pipe objects to the cmdlet `Export-CSV` which will use the property names as headers and the objects in the array as rows and the properties as columns.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Select Name, Size | Export-Csv c:\temp\filelist.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up just getting what I wanted differently which was to just use the .Name or .Size that puts it into the string.